# VBA: Get source code from website using wininet

Tags: internet-explorer, vba

So basically I have the following code:

```
Dim myIE As InternetExplorer: Set myIE = New InternetExplorer
myIE.Visible = True
myIE.Navigate URL:="http://www.google.com"
While myIE.Busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend
```

How would I be able to get the source code of the page? And it'll be nice if someone can link me to the appropriate documentation. I'm absolutely hopeless looking through MS's website.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the source HTML using:

```
strHTML = myIE.Document.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: May not be exactly the same as what was in the .html file IE downloaded.  But usually close enough.